# Difference between Release and a Change

Tags: jira, release, software-distribution, itil

Regarding software release and change management.
What is the difference between a Release and Change?
Is it the same thing?

Asking because [Jira Software](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/bug-tracking) includes Releases but [Jira Service Desk](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-service-desk-cloud/docs/what-is-jira-service-desk/) includes Change Management.

Answer (score 0):

[Change management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_management_(ITSM)) is a rather wide field and defined by the [IT Infrastructure Library (ITIL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITIL).

> **Change Management** is a process that has the goal of ensuring that all adjustments to the IT infrastructure are controlled, carried out efficiently and with minimization of risks for the operation of existing business services.

We we stick to ITIL, there is also a the following definition

> [Release management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Release_management) is the process of managing, planning, scheduling and controlling a software build through different stages and environments; including testing and deploying software releases.

Having said this, in all projects I have seen so far, a **release is most often a set of changes**.